# Error during sharing text and Image on Facebook using facebook SDK integration

Tags: facebook, android-facebook, android-sharing

i m getting error during shareing text and Image on Facebook. i used Facebook SDK 4.0 version to integrate into my app

Facebook Analytic showing no error. App opens : 58
when i click on image, Facbook opens and instantly closed, there is no post on my facebook wall. And error shwoing

```js
BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
  java.lang.Exception: Invalid JSON result
      at com.facebook.appcenter.protocol.FetchAppDetailMethod.a(FetchAppDetailMethod.java:59)
      at com.facebook.appcenter.protocol.FetchAppDetailMethod.a(FetchAppDetailMethod.java:25)
      at com.facebook.graphql.protocol.AbstractPersistedGraphQlApiMethod.a(AbstractPersistedGraphQlApiMethod.java:160)
      at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:186)
      at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:150)
      at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
      at com.facebook.appcenter.service.AppDataServiceHandler.d(AppDataServiceHandler.java:223)
      at com.facebook.appcenter.service.AppDataServiceHandler.a(AppDataServiceHandler.java:103)
      at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:296)
      at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
      at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

this is the code im using yo share text and Image

```js
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

     ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
     .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com")).build();
     shareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
}
```

here is minifest file code

```js
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider@string/facebook_app_id"
            android:exported="true" />

       <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

i declared String facebook_app_id into string.xml file 
i do not know why error is showing. i m doing nothing special.

Any suggestion will highly appreciated. thanks in Advance

Comment: do you enabled the sandbox mode in the developer page.?

Comment: can you post your entire manifest please ?

Comment: sure, i will posy my minifeast file,i did not enable sandbox mode in developer page, actually i dnot know how to enable it, please tell; me how to enable @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: Please enter your comment as Answer, it is an Answer who do not know enable the sandbox after creating app. i will accept your answer :) @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: Thank you,.. i'll will do it

Comment: do you know how to send text and image on Pintrest from (my) android app @RaguSwaminathan. i will grateful to you if you help me with pinterset  :)

Comment: If you post it as an separate question, it will be much better. please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for opening and closing the Facebook Screen instantly is due to **Sandbox settings**.

> **You need to enable the SandBox mode in the Facebook Developer
>   Page.**

*Follow the steps here.*

**Open https://developers.facebook.com/ .  Select your app from top navigation bar ( Apps ). Click on Status & Review (Left Sidebar). You will find a toggle button to do on/off your app from sandbox mode. [ From Google - This may help some beginners in future ]**.

@Ashu Kumar, Thanks for mentioning  me to post an answer regarding this.

Best Wishes.